# Memory Allocation in GPU through Renderscript

Tags: android, bitmap, renderscript

I am making 3 varieties of blurred bitmap through Renderscript on Android. After using app quite a few times, it closes automatically. Log as follows:

**V/RenderScript(4548): User-backed allocation failed stride requirement, falling back to separate allocation

D/dalvikvm(4548): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 5% free 21256K/22352K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 20ms**

Enabled largeHeap in manifest file but it's not helping. I need to clear memory in GPU via renderscript isn't it? I am not finding how to do this.

Android OS:4.4.2, Device:Samsung Note II.

Anybody knows how to handle this?

Answer (score 8):

If you're allocating memory with USAGE_SHARED (used by default in createFromBitmap) and your bitmap is not a multiple of 16 pixels wide, then you'll see that message in your log. However, it's not dangerous and wouldn't cause the app to crash.

Are you getting an actual exception when things close? It sounds like you may have some sort of leak somewhere.

Comment: Do you know if having a Bitmap which is 16*n pixel wide makes the allocation faster?

Comment: it often does--many drivers can use those bitmaps' backing store directly rather than requiring a second allocation + copy. that's what USAGE_SHARED does--use the existing backing store if possible, otherwise allocate a new one and do a copy. the other APIs remain the same (have to copy back to the Bitmap even if the backing store is shared) because of cache flushing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take that in account building my app!

Comment: @TimMurray can you have a look into this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452679/renderscript-c-style-pointer-usage-performance-issue

Comment: @TimMurray Is copying back necessary even if the shared backing store isn't a bitmap? I'm using a regular float array (16 byte memory aligned).