# Renderscript c style pointer usage performance issue

Tags: android, image-processing, android-support-library, renderscript

In render script, I am using bound pointers to iterate over a large image. 
The problem is in the array access performance.

```
...
for(int i=0; i < channels; i++) {
    sum += (input[i*input_size]) * mulValue;
}
...
```

For example, when the input_size is 12288 it takes 1.5 seconds to complete script, but when the input_size is 12280 it takes ~0.5 seconds.

What can cause such a mystery behavior?

Comment: Check that you are not accessing it out of bounds. Also, prefer rsGetElementAt_* functions to bound pointers.

Comment: @sakridge Array is too large, but I am not accessing it out of range. Can this be the result of caching ?

Comment: Could be. Maybe that size causes your algorithm to exceed one of the cache levels. Another thing is that the slower size is more aligned which could cause more bank conflicts but 3x difference seems excessive. Can you try a sweep of a bunch of different sizes?

Comment: @sakridge I've checked with larger sizes, for example, 13000 and even 19600 work faster than 12888. How can I check if it's from cache? And what techniques  I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: CPU performance counters would be your best bet then you can compare cache stats between the two runs. I'm not aware of a public supported way to get that info but you might try to get POSIX perf_event_open interface working from NDK if you're ambitious.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding the performance implications of what you write in RenderScript (or openCL) is complex.

Just writing it in RendersScript does not guarantee performance.
Many times you encounter cache coherence issues when your memory access hop around.

Quite often it is better to structure the code as a series of kernels that process in a cache friendly manner.

Sorry if this is vague. You questing does not have enough details.